# log file for storing outputs on stdout and stderr isn't created

Tags: filesystems, afs

I am running a long running script on a Scientific Linux server with Kerberos and Andrew file system, by

```
myscript.sh >log 2>&1 &
```

Upon starting the command, I didn't see a file called `log` in the current directory, but saw a file called `.__afs063D` which is logging the outputs on stdout and stderr.

The script is still running.  why is `log` not created? When will it be?

Comment: Does this happen in different shells?

Comment: i only use bash @HaukeLaging

Comment: @Tim Might be interesting to check whether the same happens with other shells.

Comment: http://wiki.openafs.org/UsageFAQ/#index19h3 may apply

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks. My case doesn't seem mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Files like `.__afs063D` are created when a process has a file descriptor [open but the file has been deleted](http://www.angelfire.com/hi/plutonic/afs-faq.html#sub2.19).  Its how the AFS cache handler handles that situation.  Next time the volume is salvaged, it will be removed.

Comment: (1) But I don't delete the log file, but redirect to it. why is the hidden file created, but my log file isn't? (2) What do you mean by " the volume is salvaged"?

Comment: Perhaps you are seeing the output of another process, and you deleted a previous version of the log file but neglected to kill off the background process?

Comment: AFS volumes are [salvaged](http://docs.openafs.org/Reference/8/salvager.html) by the volume server periodically or during maintenance (depending on how your cell is run).  Think of it as fsck for AFS, run by the AFS volume server.

Comment: My actual command is `myscript.sh > predict/log 2>&1`. In `myscript.sh`, I want to have a dir `predict` with empty content, where `myscript.sh` will create some files, but without relying on `predict` existing or being empty, so I do `rm -rf predict; mkdir -p predict`. Is that the reason?

Comment: Possibly.  It depends on the order of commands.

Comment: I use dir `predict` to store the files created by `myscript.sh` and also a log file created by redirecting  the script's stdout/stderr output. I want to have `predict` empty at the beginning of the script,  without relying on `predict` existing or being empty. What would you do if you were me, to avoid the problem in my post?